# Pointing www to one place, but keep subdomain here

Tags: domain, subdomain, cname-record, a-record, wildcard

First of all, sorry for the awful wording in the title. I will try to explain what I actually need and hopefully someone here will know if it's possible or no.
Basically I want to point my domain-name.com to a bigcartel store. This is doable if I setup the www CNAME record towards my-shop-url.bigcartel.com. The problem I'm having is that I'd like to keep my assets (CSS, JS, Images) on my current hosting account (where the domain is actually hosted), so I was thinking if I could setup something like subdomain.domain-name.com and still having the www pointed to bigcartel? I can access the files via the temporary IP/~hosting-account-name, but this isn't too pretty.

Again, sorry for being so thick, but I have basic knowledge when it comes to stuff like these.

Thanks heaps,
Seb

Comment: Sure, you could do this, if the big cartel store cooperates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - thanks for your reply. But I'm not too sure what exactly do you mean by that. Could you please be a tiny bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, you'd just need to set up your current hosting to listen for subdomain.domain-name.com, and then set up an (A) or (CNAME) record in the DNS control panel for domain-name.com which points to the IP address assigned by your current host.  If you're setting it up as an (A) record, be wary that in the future if your current host changes IP addresses (such as if they change data centers), the subdomain would break, so you'd ideally want to use a CNAME if they have some hostname you can point it to such as server123.currenthostingcompany.com (which in theory they should keep updated if they move IPs in the future).  If you can't do that you could put some website monitoring in place for the subdomain.

Comment: @Seb I hope you were able to get your issue resolved.  If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted so I can get credit for it.  Thanks